# Django middleware is executed at every API call

Tags: python, django

I created a middleware to record the activity log for user login but it executes at every API call. The `ActivityLog` is to record the entries.

Middleware.py

```
class UserActivityMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Set a flag in the session to indicate that the user has been logged in during this session
        request.session['user_logged_in'] = request.session.get('user_logged_in', False)

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Check if the user is authenticated, has just logged in, and hasn't been logged during this session
        if (
            request.user.is_authenticated
            and request.user.last_login is not None
            and request.session.get('user_logged_in', False) is False
            and not request.path.startswith('/static/')
            and not request.path.startswith('/media/')
        ):
            print("reached middleware")
            print(f"User: {request.user.username}")
            print(f"Last Login: {request.user.last_login}")
            print(f"Session Flag: {request.session.get('user_logged_in')}")
            print(f"Request Path: {request.path}")

            # Log the user login activity
            ActivityLog.objects.create(
                user=request.user,
                action="Login",
                target_model="User",
                target_object_id=request.user.id,
                details=f"User {request.user.username} logged in at {timezone.now()}."
            )

            # Set a flag in the session to indicate that the user has been logged in during this session
            request.session['user_logged_in'] = True

        return response
```

What should I do to reduce it to a single execution i.e. when the user logs in?

Comment: Yes, middleware is executed for every single request. If you want to add code specific to one view, then add the code to that view only.

Comment: @deceze I am using JWT auth to authenticate so can't really change that. Also I have set the flag `user_logged_in` but it's not really working

Comment: You can _always_ change a view, you just might have to subclass it or wrap it in another view. It's all just Python classes and function calls.